# EKS - Step function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

This question is about how to do this process. I have created a cluster named Python-Cluster with a nodegroup of 2 nodes. I wanted to deploy a python code into this pods.

```
import json
response = {}
def main(message):
    user_input = message['Payload']['Input']
    
    if user_input == 'Invoke':
        response['Output'] = "Invoked"
        response['Message'] = "First Job invoked based on the input"
        return response
```

I made this as an image and deployed using yaml as follows

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: python
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: python
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: python
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: python
        image: python-img:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: python
spec:
  selector:
    app: python
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 6000
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Now i wanted to use step function to give input to the python image. So i created an step function to run EKS job.

```
{
  "Comment": "A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using Pass states",
  "StartAt": "Run a job on an EKS Cluster",
  "States": {
    "Run a job on an EKS Cluster": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::eks:runJob.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "ClusterName": "Python-Cluster",
    "CertificateAuthority": "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",
    "Endpoint": "https://82EDCAF2DEA2FD8AF20E184476B547CB.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com",
    "Job": {
      "apiVersion": "batch/v1",
      "kind": "Job",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "my-example-job"
      },
      "spec": {
        "template": {
          "metadata": {
            "name": "my-example-job"
          },
          "spec": {
            "containers": [
              {
                "name": "python-7f7c9cdbc6-fvtvl",
                "image": "python-7f7c9cdbc6-fvtvl",
                "command": [
                  "python"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "restartPolicy": "Never"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "LogOptions": {
      "RetrieveLogs": true,
      "RawLogs": true
    }
  },
  "End": true
  }
  }
}
```

When running the state machine i get EKS.401 error, i have given step function admin access. I have added the IAM role in the config file as well... What should i do?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Can you tell about your use-case. Maybe, we can eradicate the use of step function and can provide the input via some other way.

Comment: Also, where have you stored the image's artifact?

Comment: My Use case is as follows,

I have a EKS cluster. I have a Python code for which the input should be given initially in JSON format. The output of the Python code is also a JSON format. And I need the python code to be ran using step function Job

I created the image using docker and used YAML to deploy it as pod

Comment: Can you provide the picture of the workflow that you are designing using Step functions.
Also, found this article[1] which relates to your use-case. You can have a look till the time I debug this issue further.
[1]: https://awstip.com/how-to-run-eks-job-with-aws-state-machine-5f309c9cb808

Comment: Also, can you show the exact error that you are getting ?